# Chrome print preview error

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I want to print a html page.
The html page is developed by me, this page can be printed with mozilla, ie.

In Chrome: when pressing CTRL+P it brings up the preview window, but it says: "Print preview failed", and i can't print anything.
In opera it doesn't brings up the print window, nor from pressing CTRL+P nor from Menu->Print, Safari prints a white page.

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? What kind of error can cause this problem? Is there any error log for chrome, to figure out what is wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried removing html elements, css scripts, javascripts, and i found out that one of my css file is blocking the print preview, i will go one, and will try to remove blocks from the css, i hope i can find this way where is the error.

**EDIT 2**

No success... Is there a possibility, that the css is to large for the browser to compile it? the css has imports inside, i tried to remove them, but this doesn't resolved my problem... Any other suggestions?

**EDIT 3**
I have the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.default.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/myStyle.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print"/>
```

If I comment the first include, or change the media to screen for style.default.css then the preview is generated, but with missing css rules.
The style.default.css is my global css, it has 17 other css imported into it this way:

```
@import url('jquery.ui.css');
@import ...
```

I have tried to comment the imports, and tried only with the css rules from that file. (If the error came from one of the imports, this should fix the problem), but this didn't fixed it, so i tried =the other way around, commenting the css rules, and try only with the imports, same result. Only success if i comment the whole file...

Any other suggestions? Somebody knows if chrome is logging somewhere such errors?

Comment: This happens to me when trying to "print" to pdf a very, very long (~11,000 comments) Disqus discussion, using Chrome 40.0.2214.111 m.

In chrome://plugins/ I can see that Chrome PDF Viewer is enabled, and Adobe Reader is disabled.

There is no "advanced" on the print / print-preview screen. After the error occurs, everything on that screen is disabled except [Cancel]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i found the error. 2 css rules have blocked the browser from generating the preview:

```
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

and

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Can you specify to which elements these properties where assigned ?

Comment: I guess the problem is only related to "position:fixed".
"position:fixed" and "position:absolute" can't be displayed in a printed page.
Usually, you should hide such elements using CSS, or re-think whether they can be positioned using a "position:relative" under the print CSS.

Comment: I've tried without position fixed, and the problem persisted until I removed the height properties too.

Comment: I solved the same problem by removing a single `position:fixed` (to default to `position:static`) from the div that wrapped the whole printable area.

Comment: bro, thank you a lot!!! You are a genius))!

Answer (score 4):

I know that i might be a little bit late to the party but I hope that this would help others in future.

The problem with print previews are often connected with styling. Some properties could break down our preview, and we could spend long hours before we solve this issue.

Here are some most common attributes that could induce this bug: height, position, overflow. It's a must to remember that for printing:

- `height: 100%`,
- `position: fixed/absolute/relative` (in some cases),
- `overflow: hidden`,

are 'the last nail in the coffin'.

None of container should have them set. 
For `position` you can use `static`, for `height` use `fixed values` or just leave an `auto` option. Always remember to set `overflow: visible`. Otherwise the thing we want to print could be hidden.

Also I have written a short article about printing in Ionic where I explained a topic a little bit more. You can find it here: http://blog.primemodule.com/print-style-sheets-in-ionic-framework/

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search returned [this](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/g85bvJVYxy0/YC3AadTPLnkJ):

> You may be seeing this if you disabled Chrome's PDF viewer and enabled Adobe's. Once you've done this, you will get a message as you describe.  You can still get to your printer box by clicking on Advanced in the Print Preview screen as edvrde states.
>
> Or you can disable Print Preview.  You do this by:
>
> 1. Right click on your Chrome shortcut
> 2. Go to Properties
> 3. In the Target field, go to the end of the file location and add:"  --disable-print-preview". Please include the two spaces as well. In addition, as enystrom mentioned, put this outside of the quotes if you have them. In this way, it should look like:
>      a. C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe  --disable-print-preview
>      b. "C:\Users[user name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --disable-print-preview (if you have quotation marks)
> 4. Press OK.
>
> If you are running Win 7 and have Chrome pinned to your taskbar you should remove it and to this to the Chrome icon you get to from your Start menu, then repin it to your taskbar.

Comment: This isn't a solution, I tried already everything I found in google, that's why I'm asking here. It's an end-user application, witch will be sold, so i need to fix the error in my page. Other pages from this application witch doesn't include the whole design, they are printed correctly by every browser, that's why I think it's cause is or a html or a css error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=91601), this problem won't be fixed (check the status of the bug).

The problem is related to your PDF reader. You most probably removed "Microsoft XPS document writer" or "Adobe PDF". You can solve the PDF reader problem [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/g85bvJVYxy0).
Keep in mind that the Print Preview isn't linked to the Print functionality.
You can still print the webpage without a Print Preview. In most of the browsers, the Print Preview isn't accurate. It's better to print the webpage to check the output.

Comment: the first one is a joke, the second one can't help me, i already have my working css for printig, but i can't use it with other css files, and i can't figure out why...

Comment: Yep my mistake. I didn't download the file to check it out :P
It's kind of an "eco-guerilla" prank.

You can use multiple Print CSS code:
- using multiple `link` tags: `<link media="print" type="text/css" href="print1.css" rel="stylesheet"><link media="print" type="text/css" href="print2.css" rel="stylesheet">`
- using Media Queries in your CSS code: `@media print { ...... }`

Comment: If you're using `media="screen"`, the CSS won't be applied for a printed webpage.
Usually, you should use one (or many) CSS files with `media="all"` to target all the devices, and you should provide a print-version which overrides the default CSS files. Same goes for CSS mobile versions. It's easier to do and you avoid duplicating the code.
For another project, you should look into CSS Frameworks (Foundation, Bootstrap etc.).

Comment: Yes, i know how to use them. It seems the problem cause is bootstrap... if I comment out bootstrap css import the problem is solved, but i have used to many bootstrap items to comment it out... Still searching...

Comment: Just use one Bootstrap version.
Bootstrap shouldn't create problems ... it's an amazing library.

Comment: I use bootstrap v3.0.0 for js, and for css also. I know it's an amazing library, this is why i can't understand what is going wrong...

Comment: Try to print the page using Chrome and check if there's an error. I've being working for more than 2 years on CSS Print versions (using LTR and RTL), I had a nightmare with WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari). You can't rely on the Print Preview, you need to print the webpage. My 2 cents.

Comment: the problem is, it says nothing to print... print preview failed error is shown, and 0 pages to print

Comment: You need to install a Adobe PDF or Microsoft XPS document writer or any other printing device. You probably don't have any listed printers.

Comment: I have printers installed, and pdf printers too, i fixed the problem, below is the solution

Answer (score 0):

For me it was caused by chrome print unable to handle this div style that I use to display a progress circle:
[image]

```
style={`background: radial-gradient(closest-side, ${bg} 40%, transparent 80% 100%),
                conic-gradient(${fg} ${progress}%, ${emptyBg} 0);
                width:${size}; height:${size}`}
```

I had to proceed by dichotomy to find out the origin in [my page for creating resumes](https://cvlink.in).

You can find more info about the bug here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/edit/751546/comment/1316344?comment=question#comment-1316344