# Cannot print a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am using this code to print a specific div

CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    * {
        display:none;
    }
    #printportion {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

Script

```
<script>
    var printCalender=function () {
        setTimeout(window.print, 1500);
    }
</script>
```

When I run my page in google chrome, the print preview window is blank and shows 'print preview failed'

Comment: i guess this question can provide throw some light. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928182/chrome-print-preview-error

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that regardless of where your targeted element is positioned in the DOM, your `*` selector will match any and all parents it has (including `<html>` and `<body>`) so the element will never be shown.
See the below example:

```css
* {
  display: none;
}
#showme {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="showme">This will never be shown</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Nit said the problem is with your `*` selector. You can use one selector with `@media print` like this:

```css
@media print {
  body.print-element *:not(.print) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Here you have a working example where you can print any clicked element and/or the entire normal HTML document:

```js
function print_this(elem) {
  document.body.classList.add('print-element')
  elem.classList.add('print')
  window.print()
  document.body.classList.remove('print-element')
  elem.classList.remove('print')
}

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(elem => 
  elem.onclick = () => print_this(elem))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #e9a9c7;
  color: #39464e;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media print {
  body.print-element *:not(.print) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Print 1</div>
<div>Print 2</div>
```

**Note**: if you cannot see colors remember to click Background Graphic (Chrome) or similar in your print options.